# Two auto-renewing subscription with trial periods

Tags: ios, subscription, trial, auto-renewing

I'm developer of iOS / OS X app.

I would like to make two auto-renewable subscriptions (in one "family" of subscriptions).
1) Monthly subscription + 1 month trial
2) Yearly subscription + 1 month trial (or, may be, 3 months trial)

My quastion:

If a user switches form a monthly subscription to an annual subscription plan will she or he get an additional trial period which it set up for an annual subscription plan?

**Edit:** The answer is "No". User may get trial period only one time. He wouldn't get additional trials after plan changing/resubscribtion etc.